# Not vertical centering in multirow at \newline

Tags: tables, multirow

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|}\hline
X & Y \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No problem} & One Line \\ \cline{2-1} 
                        & Two Line \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Problem} & One Line \\ \cline{2-1} 
                     & 1 \newline 2 \newline 3 \newline 4\\ \hline   
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

displaying

[image].

About One Line,1,2,3,4 rows in Y column, It sees like two rows. How it sees five rows? That is, "Problem" in X column, will vertical centering.

[I am sorry, my English.]

Comment: Replace `\multirow{2}` with `\multirow{5}`.

Comment: @Bernard, perfect working.

Comment: A basis to work with such situations: if you have multilined cells next to a multirow, count the number of of `lines`, not the number of rows, and adjust if necessary.

Comment: @Paul Gessler: Done (added some details about manual adjustments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `\multirow{2}` with `\multirow{5}`. Indeed `\multirow`  seems to be done for one-lined cells, and in case of multilined cells, one should count the number of lines rather than the number of rows, and make some manual adjustment if necessary, to take into account the thickness of intermediate lines, extra vertical spacing between rows (`\extrarowheight` from the `array` package, `\addlinespace`, `\aboverulesep`, `belowrulesep` and the like from `booktabs`, &c.).